# Looking for a payment gateway

Tags: python, payment-gateway, payment

I'm looking for a payment gateway company so we can avoid tiresome PCI-DSS certification and its associated expenses. I'll get this out the way now, **I don't want Paypal.** It does what I want but it's really not a company I want to trust with any sort of money.

It needs to support the following flow:

- User performs actions on our site, generating an amount that needs to be paid.
- Our server contacts the gateway asynchronously (no hidden inputs) and tells it about the user, how much they need to pay. The gateway returns a URL and perhaps a tentative transaction ID.
- Our server stores the transaction ID and redirects the user to the URL provided by the gateway.
- The user fills out their payment details on the remote server.
- When they have completed that, the gateway asynchronously contacts our server with the outcome, transaction id, etc and forwards them back to us (at a predestined URL).
- We can show the user their order is complete/failed/etc. Fin.

If at all possible, UK or EU based and developer friendly.

We don't need any concept of a shopping basket as we have that all handled in our code already.

We have (or at least will have by launch) a proper merchant banking account - so cover services like Paypay aren't needed.

If their API covers Python (we're using Django) explicitly, all the better but I think I'm capable enough to decipher any other examples and transcode them into Python myself.

Comment: I would ask anybody tempted to click on the **close** button to reconsider. a) I'm trying to get work done - I'd appreciate the help - and b) there are plenty of other lazyweb-style questions on SO.

Comment: You can check [payex payment gateway](http://payex.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at Adyen (www.adyen.com). They are European and provide a whole lot of features and a very friendly interface. They don't charge a monthly or set up fee and seem to be reasonably priced per transaction.

Their hosted payments page can be completely customised which was an amazing improvement for us.

Answer (score 4):

I've used extensively TrustCommerce (http://www.trustcommerce.com/tclink.php), its python API is plain and simple and very easy to use, I have a bunch of Zope applications that use it on a daily basis for years without any major interruptions.

Answer (score 2):

I just finished something exactly like this using **First Data Global Gateway** (don't really want to provide a link, can find with Google).  There's no Python API because their interface is nothing but http POST.

You have the choice of gathering credit card info yourself before posting the form to their server, as long as the connection is SSL and the referring URL is known to them (meaning it's your form but you can't store or process the data first).

In the FDGG gateway "terminal interface" you configure your URL endpoints for authorization accepted/failed and it will POST transaction information.

I can't say it was fun and their "test" mode was buggy but it works.  Sorry, don't know if it's available in UK/EU but it's misnamed if it isn't :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like Worldpay or even Google Checkout. But it all depends what your turnover is, because these sorts of providers (who host the payment page themselves), tend to take a percentage of every transaction, rather than a fixed monthly fee that you can get from elsewhere.

The other thing to consider is, if you have any way of taking orders over the phone, and the phone operators need to take customers' credit card details, then your whole internal network will need to be PCI compliant, too.

If you JUST need it for a website, then that makes it easier. If you have a low turnover, then check out the sites mentioned above. If you have a high turnover, then it may work out more cost effective in the long run to get PCI-DSS certified and still keep control of credit card transactions in-house, giving you more flexibility, and cheaper transaction costs.

Answer (score 0):

[stripe](http://www.stripe.com) seems to be the hot new payment processing startup now. I'm using them and I like them a lot, the API is very simple. However, they are new and may not have all the bells and whistles like some older processors.